# How can I get request from the client with JSON data and fileupload via JAX-RS(Jersey)?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I need to get the request from the client with JSON data and an Image file in a single request via JAX-Rs. How can I receive it in the server side Java application to process it further.

```
@POST
@Path("/path")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public String get(@Context UriInfo uriInfo,
        final MyDTO myDTO,
        @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream inputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
}
```

I am having the above code but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is code from working project. Send file data and some meta. Try the same.

```
    @POST
    @Path("import")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
    @RolesAllowed(SystemRoles.ADMIN)
    public void importScenario(@FormDataParam("importScenario") final InputStream is,
            @FormDataParam("complectId") final Long complectId) {
        LOG.debug("start import file");
        if (is == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageBundle.get(InnerMessage.NO_FILE));
        }
        try {
            LOG.debug("start execute import bean");
            importService.importScenarioOrComplect(is, complectId);
            LOG.debug("end execute import bean");
        } catch (FileStorageException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        } catch (STCoreException e) {
            throw new EJBException(MessageBundle.get(InnerMessage.CRITICAL_ERROR), e);
        } finally {
            LOG.debug("end import file");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you update this code for receiving a JSON data along with the file uploaded from the client?

Comment: You need to create correct json on browser side. And change method signature to recive java object with same fields name.